# Minimum value of sum of angles

Tags: geometry

> Let $Q$ is a point on or inside the boundary of a square
>
> $ABCD.$ Then the minimum value of
>
> $\angle QAB+\angle QBC+\angle QCD+\angle QDA$ is

what i try

If i take point inside the square. then from geometry

we have $\displaystyle \angle QAB+\angle QBC+\angle QCD+\angle QDA=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{4}=\pi$

How do i solve it, please show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The four angles are $={\pi\over4}$ each only when $Q$ is at the center of the square.

Assume that the square is $S:=[-1,1]^2$. The sum $f(x,y)$ of the four angles is then undefined when $(x,y)$ is one of the vertices $A=(1,1)$, $B=(-1,1)$, $C=(-1,-1)$, $D=(1,-1)$, and it is impossible to create a continuous extension of $f$ to these vertices.  This implies that $f$ does not need to assume a minimum on $S$. In fact, looking at a figure shows that $f(0.9999,1)\approx{3\pi\over4}$ and $f(1,0.9999)\approx{5\pi\over4}$. Inspecting the graph of $f$ I come to the conclusion that
$$\inf_{(x,y)\in S}f(x,y)={3\pi\over4}\ .$$